# Should php be used to make every webpage on a website or only when some database query is involved

Tags: php, html

New to the world of **php** and dynamic websites I'm consfused as weather to use  **php** from now on even to *make basic webpages* or continue making webpages with html and **only** use php when some data Insertion,Retrieval etc.. action to a database using ***SQL queries*** is required.. from a website

Don't know if I answered my own question 
Clarification is highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: If a particular page has no functionality to write in PHP, what PHP code would you put on that page in the first place?

Comment: ok and by functionality does it mean PHP is only used when data needs to be sent to or retrieved from a database or am I just narrowing the scope for where PHP can be applied to on websites

Comment: PHP certainly does more than *just* interact with a database.  You'd use server-side code any time you have some server-side functionality to perform.  If there's no functionality, then there's no code to write.

Comment: An example of server side functionality other than database would really sum it up

Comment: Creating a layout or header file which would be used in an `include()` on other pages, rather than re-writing it on every page, is one example.  Sending email is another.  Performing any kind of calculation, really.  Interacting with some other off-site service.  etc.  etc.

Comment: if you need write an email automatically you use php.
if you need keep session you use php.

For me, the use of php is not only involved in database operations

Comment: Just use PHP from the start.  As you enhance your experience, you will save yourself extra work in the future.  The only thing with using .php pages is that you need a local server to see your website in the browser.   With .html pages, you do not need a local server.  But think this way, sooner or later, the simplest webpage you worked on, will require extra work and that is when your .php pages come handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think PHP *does*, but if there's no server-side functionality to put on a particular page then there wouldn't *be* any PHP code to write.

For example, if you have a page like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is my page!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Obviously an over-simplified example, but you get the idea...)

Well, if that's the page, then you don't need any PHP code.  So why would you "use PHP" when there's no code to write for it?

When there's some server-side functionality that needs to happen, write code for it.  When there isn't... well... don't write code for it.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no dynamic elements within the webpage, then it is not necessary to write the page in a PHP file; an HTML file will suffice. That said, I would recommend saving the page as a PHP file anyways, because you may find yourself needing dynamic PHP functionality later, in which case you would need to convert the file then. By using PHP files in the first place, you will likely be saving yourself an extra step in the future.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not used just for contents saved in database, but also for contents that are static also such as header and footer section, imagine that your website is about 50 pages, and if you want to change one menu link! you have to edit all 50 web pages while using PHP is only needs to change one file that you included for main page.
In my website, I programmed those section with PHP:

1. Navigation menus
2. Header and Footer
3. Blog section

Answer (score 0):

I use .php pages for all my webpages because eventually, I use a php code inside any of the pages to call from the simplest (header, footer) to buttons, insert texts, codes, anything that may need repetitive work but can be linked to its relevant .php document.  And if any change is needed, one can simply change the one page and it will change everywhere.  Dynamic works for me, even if I do not necessarily add a database to it.